# Chrome Extension with Google OAuth in .Net core

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm building a Chrome Extension that connects to a .net 5 server for handling all the heavy works. It typically needs to call Google APIs, hence must be OAuth2.0 authenticated. Here is how I approach this:

**First approach:** Authentication in Chrome Extension

- Use `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` to retrieve an access token in the service worker and pass it to backend server.
- Backend server will then make API callsusing the served token.

The drawback of this approach is it won't work for the long-run background tasks in backend as the access token might be expired during the task and client's chrome browser is closed (hence, can't send a new token to the backend).

**Second approach:** Backend handles authentication

- Make backend server handle the authentication and exchange for a new token upon expiration.
- When chrome extension makes a request to backend, if the request hasn't been authenticated/authorized, backend signals back the url and extension redirects user to a new tab and asks user to sign in and to grant access.

There are some uncertainties about the second one:

- How do we identify whether a request has authenticated by oauth2.0? (My guess is via cookie)
- I've been following this guide https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth but have not been able to authenticate on post request (when UI calling this).

I'm super new to this OAuth world. It doesn't seem like the JWT bearer token process.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if the user is not logged in into Chrome (anonymous window, ...). From chrone.identity documentation (first approach): *Fetching a token may require the user to sign-in to Chrome, or approve the application's requested scopes."* I think some users won't do that.

Comment: @Michael that's good point, it will fail in this case. However, I'm not really digging into first approach as my extension uses backend heavily so ability to fetch fresh token is required.

Comment: Then you have a second decision: If it's possible to fetch user specific data (for which you need the access token) on the client I would do that. Then you send this data to your API and perform further processing. Google supports JavaScript much more than .NET for its APIs.